Shiny.router fails to load more than two pages
I am trying to build a Shiny dashboard with Fluent, including several pages and a navigation bar. It is based on this tutorial: https://appsilon.github.io/shiny.fluent/articles/st-sales-reps-dashboard.html
I have managed to create the overall structure. I wish to have four distinct pages for navigation (home, profile, analysis and recommendations). I created all four pages (home_page, profile_page, analysis_page and recos_page).
I have followed the approach of the tutorial for the pieces of code involving shiny.router, i.e.:
Definition of the UI:
router <- router_ui(
    route("/", home_page),
    route("profile", profile_page),
    route("analysis", analysis_page),
    route("recos", recos_page)
    
)

ui <- fluentPage(
    layout(router),
    tags$head(
        tags$link(href = "style.css", rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css")
    ))

Server:
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    router_server()
    }

shinyApp(ui, server)


The code works perfectly fine when I have only two pages (regardless of which ones).

When I try to add three or more pages in the router_ui function, no page is loaded:

I cannot understand this behavior. I've seen in the documentation that there was something about dynamic routes but I am not sure this is relevant...
